# I'm having an issue when running my build

Tags: flutter, dart

So I try building my flutter code and get the error:

```
"H:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/chewie-0.9.10/lib/src/chewie_player.dart:277:51: Error: Too many positional
Try removing the extra positional arguments.
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)"
```

Here is the code snippet in question

```
  static ChewieController of(BuildContext context) {
    final chewieControllerProvider =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(_ChewieControllerProvider)
            as _ChewieControllerProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a version mismatch between Flutter and `chewie_player`.

In version 0.9.10, the code is as you have used it.

However, in the latest version, it is,

```
static ChewieController of(BuildContext context) {
  final chewieControllerProvider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ChewieControllerProvider>();

  return chewieControllerProvider.controller;
}
```

which should the correct way according to your `flutter` version since the function `context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` doesn't take any `positional` parameters.

Just update your dependency to `chewie: ^1.0.0`.

This should fix it.